Getting permissions errors when running dev container with podman
I am trying to launch a simple dev-container:
using wsl on windows
running ubuntu 24.04 LTS
podman version 4.9.3
with the following:
devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy",
    "containerEnv": {
      "HOME": "/home/vscode"
    },
    "containerUser": "vscode",
    "remoteUser": "vscode",
    "runArgs": [
        "--userns=keep-id"
    ]
}

Its failing with permissions errors:
[2024-07-12T22:51:43.769Z] Start: Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9
[2024-07-12T22:51:49.774Z] Stop (6005 ms): Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9
[2024-07-12T22:51:49.778Z] Start: Starting container
[2024-07-12T22:51:49.780Z] Start: Run: podman start 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:51:55.293Z] 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:51:55.300Z] Stop (5520 ms): Run: podman start 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:51:55.301Z] Stop (5523 ms): Starting container
[2024-07-12T22:51:55.301Z] Start: Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04\home\theghostjw\pyrethrum --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/home/theghostjw/pyrethrum/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[2024-07-12T22:52:00.523Z] Stop (5222 ms): Run: podman ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04\home\theghostjw\pyrethrum --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/home/theghostjw/pyrethrum/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[2024-07-12T22:52:00.524Z] Start: Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9
[2024-07-12T22:52:05.733Z] Stop (5209 ms): Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9
[2024-07-12T22:52:05.745Z] Start: Inspecting container
[2024-07-12T22:52:05.746Z] Start: Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:11.121Z] Stop (5375 ms): Run: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:11.122Z] Stop (5377 ms): Inspecting container
[2024-07-12T22:52:11.127Z] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[2024-07-12T22:52:11.139Z] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.783Z] x86_64
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.783Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.783Z] Stop (5644 ms): Run in container: uname -m
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.784Z] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.793Z] PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.793Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.794Z] Stop (10 ms): Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.796Z] Start: Run in container:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'vscode' || grep -E '^vscode|^[^:]*:[^:]*:vscode:' /etc/passwd || true)
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.810Z] Stop (14 ms): Run in container:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'vscode' || grep -E '^vscode|^[^:]*:[^:]*:vscode:' /etc/passwd || true)
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.817Z] Start: Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcEnvironmentMarker'
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.823Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.823Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.823Z] Stop (6 ms): Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcEnvironmentMarker'
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.824Z] Start: Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcProfileMarker'
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.829Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.830Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.830Z] Stop (6 ms): Run in container: test -f '/var/devcontainer/.patchEtcProfileMarker'
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.832Z] Stop (42827 ms): Resolving Remote
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.875Z] Stop (61153 ms): Run in Host: /home/theghostjw/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729/node /home/theghostjw/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.377.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --docker-path podman --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-63037fe6-a084-4f0d-98bf-5e57d2a2285a1720824615428 --workspace-folder /home/theghostjw/pyrethrum --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04\home\theghostjw\pyrethrum --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/home/theghostjw/pyrethrum/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/theghostjw/pyrethrum/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[2024-07-12T22:52:16.881Z] Start: Run in Host: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:20.579Z] Stop (3698 ms): Run in Host: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:20.582Z] Start: Run in Host: podman exec -i -u root 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e /bin/sh -c echo "New container started. Keep-alive process started." ; export VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=63037fe6-a084-4f0d-98bf-5e57d2a2285a1720824615428 ; /bin/sh
[2024-07-12T22:52:20.586Z] Start: Inspecting container
[2024-07-12T22:52:20.587Z] Start: Run in Host: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:24.624Z] Stop (4037 ms): Run in Host: podman inspect --type container 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e
[2024-07-12T22:52:24.626Z] Stop (4040 ms): Inspecting container
[2024-07-12T22:52:24.717Z] Start: Run in Host: podman exec -i -u vscode -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=63037fe6-a084-4f0d-98bf-5e57d2a2285a1720824615428 0836906071a9c7fd9fa50f95bfdf37d6fb32abc3eef01099048380866dc4ed1e /bin/sh
[2024-07-12T22:52:24.734Z] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[2024-07-12T22:52:24.768Z] New container started. Keep-alive process started.
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.087Z] x86_64
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.089Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.089Z] Stop (5355 ms): Run in container: uname -m
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.090Z] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.101Z] PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.102Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.103Z] Stop (13 ms): Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.104Z] Start: Run in container:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'vscode' || grep -E '^vscode|^[^:]*:[^:]*:vscode:' /etc/passwd || true)
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.122Z] Stop (18 ms): Run in container:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'vscode' || grep -E '^vscode|^[^:]*:[^:]*:vscode:' /etc/passwd || true)
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.128Z] Start: Setup shutdown monitor
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.132Z] Forking shutdown monitor: c:\Users\thegh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.377.0\dist\shutdown\shutdownMonitorProcess \\.\pipe\vscode-remote-containers-0c6b80b6-6497-43a4-995b-32aca8495d33-sock singleContainer Debug c:\Users\thegh\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20240713T084835\window1\exthost\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers 1720824621749
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.219Z] Stop (91 ms): Setup shutdown monitor
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.228Z] Start: Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-server'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.245Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.246Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.247Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.248Z] Stop (20 ms): Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-server'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.250Z] Start: Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-remote'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.261Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.262Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.263Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.264Z] Stop (14 ms): Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-remote'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.266Z] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.284Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.286Z] mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/node': Permission denied
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.287Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.288Z] Stop (22 ms): Run in container: test ! -f '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.291Z] Start: Run in container: cat /home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.305Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.306Z] cat: /home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json: No such file or directory
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.308Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.309Z] Stop (18 ms): Run in container: cat /home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.315Z] Start: Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.336Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.338Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.342Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.343Z] Stop (28 ms): Run in container: test -d '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.344Z] Start: Run in container: test -d '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.357Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.358Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.359Z] Stop (15 ms): Run in container: test -d '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.360Z] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin' && ln -snf '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729' '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.376Z] 
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.378Z] mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/node': Permission denied
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.380Z] Exit code 1
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.383Z] Stop (23 ms): Run in container: mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin' && ln -snf '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729' '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.415Z] Command in container failed: mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin' && ln -snf '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729' '/home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.416Z] mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/node': Permission denied
[2024-07-12T22:52:30.417Z] Exit code 1

How do I change my setup to get this to work?

What's your user ID and the user ID of vscode inside the container? I guess, the IDs are different. Here is the reference for devcontainer.json and here is the reference for userns. Is this "HOME": "/home/vscode" failed a typo?

Yep typo fixed. Thanks. Will check out the link.
